# People nearby and bonjour not working over the same wireless and wired network

Tags: networking, empathy, file-sharing

I'm trying to send files from one computer to the other using empathy, but on my desktop and laptop, Empathy is only picking up Pidgin's bonjour account on both computers. (I've got Pidgin installed so that Mxit works).

I'm using the same network, with the laptop over wireless and the desktop over wired, no PPPoE. Samba is installed on the desktop, but not the laptop. Also, I can't access the Desktop computer's shares from the laptop. What could the cause of the problem be?

Answer (score 1):

If both computers are invisible for each other, this could be a setting in your router.

In my router I have to check the option "All computers are in the same IP-network", to be able to connect to other local computers.

If this doesn't solve your problem please post the local IP-addresses of both computers.